# Commit Multiple Local Repos to One Remote Repo (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control

The Problem: 
I have two local repos with the same project, but different versions (when I started the project, I created a copy of a file and didn't realize I was making copies of the entire local repo). Now, I want to commit the contents of both of them. 
I committed the first one to the remote repo just fine. However, when I go to commit the second one, I get a conflict error and it fails to commit. 
 What I've read:
 I read a post on Stack Overflow about the conflict error that suggested it popped up because there was a duplicate copy of the repo in the way, so I assumed that my issue was the fact that I had two local repos and one was getting in the way of the other. I thought of committing between local repos, but I read in a different post that that is not allowed in SVN. My only other thought is to commit one, delete it, and then make the second one the new local repo somehow. But then I'm afraid that if I delete the first local repo, that will cause issues with the remote repo.

So, my question is: is there a way that I can commit both of them to the remote repo that I am overlooking?

I am new to version control so any advice is appreciated.

Edit for clarity:
I suppose according to the svn docs, I should say that I created two repositories with local access on my desktop. By remote, I mean a repo that is on a network. The two on my desktop are for the same project. One is a version that I worked on a while ago, then I made a copy of it and worked from the copy. Now, I want to commit the first to the repo on the network to capture the first set of changes. Then I want to commit the second to capture the latest set of changes. I know my approach was not the way version control works. I should have one repo and commit changes from that repo instead of making copies, but I'm trying to fix that now.

Comment: There **are not** such things as "Local repo" and "Remote Repo" in SVN. I can't reconstruct your initial mistake you must to write it with more details in *plain English ordinary everyday words*. Two different WCs with different changes?

Comment: Alright thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: Still not clean. Three repositories? how you got such case? Step by step...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure how I can make it more clear. I said that I made a copy of the one I had on the Desktop twice.